# Solve for the points on the graph where the tangent plane is parallel using calculus

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, tangent-line

Find the points on the graph of $z = xy^{3}+8y^{-1}$ where the tangent plane is parallel to $ 2x+7y+2z=0$

I have no idea how to approach this question and have not yet taken any form of linear algebra. Is it possible to solve this question only using calculus?

Comment: find where the gradient of $f(x,y,z)=xy^3+8y^{-1}-z$ is parallel to the vector $(2,7,2)$

Comment: @WW1 how do I find the gradient?

Comment: $$\vec \nabla f =  \left(  \frac { \partial f}{\partial x}, \frac { \partial f}{\partial y}, \frac { \partial f}{\partial z} \right )
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$f(x,y,z)=xy^3+8y^{-1}-z$$

First we want to find the gradient of this function:

\begin{align}\vec\nabla f&=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y},\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right)\\
&=\left(y^3, 3xy^2-8y^{-2},-1\right)
\end{align}

Now we want to find values where this is parallel to the vector $(2,7,2)$. Two vectors are parallel if their [cross product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CrossProduct.html) is zero, so we want to find:

$$\left(y^3, 3xy^2-8y^{-2},-1\right)\times (2,7,2)=0 $$

We can find this through the following formula:

$$\underline u\times \underline v = \underline{i}(u_yv_z-u_zv_y)+ \underline j(u_xv_z-u_zv_x)+\underline k(u_xv_y-u_yv_x)$$

where $\underline i, \underline j, \underline k$ are the unit vectors

So, we have \begin{align}\underline{i}\left(2\left(3xy^2-8y^{-2}\right)+7\right)+ \underline j\left(2y^3+2\right)+\underline k\left(7y^3-2\left(3xy^2-8y^{-2}\right)\right)&=0\underline i+0\underline j+0\underline k\end{align}

We can equate coefficients to get the following simultaneous equations

\begin{align}2\left(3xy^2-8y^{-2}\right)+7&=0\tag{$\underline i$}\\
2y^3+2&=0\tag{$\underline j$}\\
7y^3-2\left(3xy^2-8y^{-2}\right)&=0\tag{$\underline k$}\end{align}

Can you continue from here?

Comment: You found the points where the tangent plane is orthogonal to the line.

Comment: @RafaBudría Two vectors are parallel when their cross product is zero ([source](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParallelVectors.html)). Two vectors are orthogonal when their dot product is zero ([source](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrthogonalVectors.html))

Comment: I asked this question since it was part of the suggested homework my professor assigned for the exam but clearly we were never taught this so I didn't know this method of solving. Thank you for showing me the method regardless as I now understand how to solve this problem.